# Chrome download bar Slowing AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ng-grid

I'm having an issue only in Chrome where it seems that the download bar is interfering with my AngularJS app.

The process goes like this. I have a grid, using Ng-grid, on the page which displays around 3000 rows of data. I have a filter function that alters the filterText of the grid. All of this code works fine until after I've exported something and Chromes download bar pops up at the bottom of the page. My export function just takes whatever the user has highlighted from the grid and exports it to a csv file.

Once this is done, if the user tries to reset the filterText of the grid back to empty the page lags horribly, Chrome throws some error pop-ups, and will sometimes crash. There is no error in the console log and I have debugged and haven't found any errors thrown in there either.

The strange thing is that if you have Chrome open, and the download bar is already present then the above steps will work and the page will be fine. It only happens when the download bar first pops up on the page. If you filter the grid and then go to a different tab and download something, and the download bar pops up, then go back to the app tab and try and clear the filters it still freezes/lags.

I'm not sure what the problem is because all the code works fine if the download bar hasn't popped up or is already up before I export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unsure what the root cause of the issue was, but by upgrading my ng-grid.js from 2.0.7 to 2.0.11 seems to have fixed the issue.